# Creating a new partition in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gparted

I am a new user for ubuntu and my hard disk had been formatted 
I need to create a new partition to copy my backup on

Comment: do you have free space to create a new parition?

Comment: Use GParted. Here is youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TK5YezY-Xc)

Answer (score 2):

To do it you can use the default GUI application found in your system. from your dash search for `disks`.

[image]

Another great application is to use [Gparted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gparted/). you can install it using

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

[image]

---

If you want to do it GLI

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdX
```

press m then enter. this will print the help message.

```
Command action
   a   toggle a bootable flag
   b   edit bsd disklabel
   c   toggle the dos compatibility flag
   d   delete a partition
   l   list known partition types
   m   print this menu
   n   add a new partition
   o   create a new empty DOS partition table
   p   print the partition table
   q   quit without saving changes
   s   create a new empty Sun disklabel
   t   change a partition's system id
   u   change display/entry units
   v   verify the partition table
   w   write table to disk and exit
   x   extra functionality (experts only)
```

Now to create a new partition press n

```
Partition type:
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended
```

press p for primary or e for extended...

complete the  procedure then when you finish press `w` to save and exit.